# Using Perl to capture ADB logcat into a txt file and then stop/save txt file when string is found

Tags: perl, adb, logcat

using Perl and ADB commands I am looking to capture a logcat log and simultaneously save to a text file (whilst perfoming a manual PLMN search on a mobile handset).  I am more familiar with Python, but legacy reasons require I use Perl.

during the log capture I am hoping to wait for a the following logcat string >> /EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED/ << before saving/stop capturing the log and then exiting.

I have made an attempt in the script below with the help of a few online pointers, but the script never exits, which leads me to conclude that my method is probably too simplistic for the task in hand.  Would anyone be able to direct me on where I am going wrong, or indeed if this task is possible?  Thanks.

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use diagnostics;

     sleep(5);
     system('adb wait-for-device');
     my $CollectLog = system('adb logcat > logcat.txt');
     my @Lines = split("\n", $CollectLog);

  # process lines
  foreach my $Line ( @Lines )
  {
        if($CollectLog =~ /EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED/m)
        {
            print "string matches the pattern\n";
            system('adb logcat -d'); 
            last;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to open a socket to the ADB service and execute the logcat via the shell command.  You can then simply process the output using the standard IO::Handle::getline().

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;

# Connect to the local ADB service
my $adbsock = IO::Socket::INET->new('127.0.0.1:5037') || die "Cannot connect to ADB service: $!";
# Connect to the device
my $data = 'host:transport-usb';
$adbsock->write(sprintf("%04X%s",length($data), $data));
$adbsock->read($data, 4);
die "connect connect to USB device" unless $data eq "OKAY";
# Execute logcat
$data = 'shell:logcat';
$adbsock->write(sprintf("%04X%s",length($data), $data));
$adbsock->read($data, 4);
die "Cannot execute logcat" unless $data eq "OKAY";
# Process the lines
my @fifo;
while(defined( my $line = $adbsock->getline())) {
    push @fifo, $line;
    shift @fifo if (scalar(@fifo) > 100);
    if($line =~ /EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED/) {
        # dump the FIFO queue
        print @fifo;
        last;
    }
}
```

There are two assumptions for the above:

1. The local ADB service is running correctly (the OP method of running 'adb wait-for-device' should accomplish this)
2. There is only one device attached and it's attached via USB

There is a (fairly terse) reference to the protocol [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/OVERVIEW.TXT) and the commands you can execute [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/SERVICES.TXT).  From experience, not all work exactly as described, so I would suggest experimentation.

PS.  Apologies for resurrecting an old question, but I encountered the same problem and found the answers to this one were not quite suitable for my purpose.

Comment: Actually I overlooked the original problem.  The OP had used logcat instead of 'logcat -d' in the first 'system'.  This command will never return.  Additionally, it redirects STDOUT to a file, so it would also never return any output.  The answer from Nathaniel addresses both of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is module for this, called expect: http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod

Your problem that system forks and does not return anything. You should use backtick, but expect is better suited for this job.

```
  use Expect;
  use Data::Dumper;

  # create an Expect object by spawning another process
  my $exp = Expect->spawn('adb wait-for-device') or die "Cannot spawn 'adb wait-for-device': $!\n";
  ### wait timeout sec or the string 
  $exp->expect($timeout,'-re',/EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED/);
  ### get everything before this string
  my $CollectLog = $exp->exp_before();
  ### print out
  print Dumper($CollectLog);
  # if no longer needed, do a soft_close to nicely shut down the command
  $exp->soft_close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply user1126070.  I should have mentioned that I am running this on Windows7, and my understanding from reading forums is that the Expect module does not run on Windows.  Do you have any other alternatives avoiding Expect, or is that going to complicate matters?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a piped open to stream the data from 'adb' and then writing the log yourself:

```
open my $OUT, "> logcat.txt" or die;
open my $IN, "adb logcat |" or die;

while (<$IN>) {
  if (/EVENT_NETWORK_SCAN_COMPLETED/) {
    `adb logcat -d`
    last;
  }
}
close $OUT;
close $IN;
```

I'm not sure about this working under Windows, though.

A (lousy) fallback would be to start the log writing in one process, then continually open the file for reading `seek` to your last position, and read to the end searching for your halt-string.